# Recommended ways of building data science teams

Tags: machine-learning

I'm not sure if this questions belongs to this place. But I will be very interested in knowing the answer. I work for the Public Administration in Spain. We want to build a data science team, and in order to do it well, I want to know what in other large companies (like a bank, for example) are doing:

- How many people usually work in the area of data science? And how are they distributed into teams?
- What are their roles?
- With respect to projects, how many people work for a particular data-science project?

If you work for a big company and can answer this questions, I will be really grateful.

Comment: Choosing the right statistical software, in which you train your people and build legacy code, is very important. I would suggest a combination of R and SPSS. R is most powerful. SPSS is quickest to use for standard things, like linear regression or factor analysis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. We have SAS licenses, but we were thinking to switch to Python, as it is becoming more standard in most companys, or at least that is what I read... 
Anyway, my question was more centered in the human factor of the data science team.

Comment: Python is good, a lot like R. Stay away from SAS... Regarding the human capital: only you know the scope and frequency of your current and future needs.